# Interpolation in the Rails Form

Tags: html, sql, ruby-on-rails

I am building the form using Rails. I am doing it like below code.

```
<%= f.label :filename, "Static File name", class: "new-schedule-label" %>
<%= f.text_field :filename, class: "form-control" %>
```

All I want is interpolate the value, example (if :filename is orders it should save in SQL as "orders" ("#{:filename}") ). Please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: Can u paste the whole form code here?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve by that way?

Comment: Simple, If someone enters **order** in the textfield then it should save in SQL as "order", I mean with quotation even if user didn't give it in textbox @NarasimhaReddy

Comment: @MenporulPoriyalan, explain in more details so that i can help you.

Comment: Simple, You better do this in before save callback. @MenporulPoriyalan

Comment: You mean in controller? @NarasimhaReddy

Comment: Nope, Inside Model. We'll be having active record callbacks http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html. You can you before save callback and append extra quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
class ThisIsYourModel

    before_save :set_quotes_to_filename

    private

    def set_quotes_to_filename
      self.filename = "'#{self.filename.tr("\'", "")}'" 
    end 

end
```

If are make sure to  not append twice, remove if user already enter quotes using this `string.tr("\'", "")`

Comment: Thanks, It Works :D !!